# Passing site properties with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, properties, jquery-selectors

So ive sort of conjured up a make shift way to do site properties, but am wondering if there is a way to improve my method. The objective is to have 1 html file where my client will be able to use a cms tool and update common values on the site such as repeated headers, thank you messages, company name, etc. I would like to use Javascript to accomplish this.

```
var spSelectResultsTxt = $("#sp .selectResultsTxt");
$(".main-content .selectResultsTxt").text(spSelectResultsTxt.text());​
```

Heres an active fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/trobbins26/VwtWD/4/

The script passes a text value from one div (which the client will update in a cms) to a class on some page in the site. The only problem is I don't want to create a var for every property that may exist on the site.

Is there a way in my script to say [if the #sp .class matches the .main-content .class, apply the text within the #sp .class as the text within the .main-content .class? Essentially creating one rule that can apply to every property i create.

Any feedback would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick:

HTML:

```
<!-- Represents html file that will be updated in a cms by client -->
<!-- To be included on each page of site -->
<div id="sp" style="display:none;">
    <span data-target=".main-content .selectResultsTxt">
        Select an option to see results for a specific year.    
    </span>
    <div data-target="#otherText">Some other text.</div>
</div>


<!-- represents page to apply rule -->
<div class="main-content">
    <h4><span class="selectResultsTxt"></span> testing...</h4>
    <p><span id="otherText"></span></p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#sp').children().each(function() {
    $($(this).data().target).text($(this).text());
});
```

Updated Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/VwtWD/7/
    ​

Explanation:

You just loop through the child elements of `div.sp`, then access its class and text and go looking for a matching element on the page to update.

I've made some improvements:

It's best to leave classes for identifying the target elements, and use the data- binding on the elements that store the user-entered text. It's easily accessible through the jQuery `.data()` function as in my solution above.

It'd probably also be nice to be able to specify the full CSS path for each element, so you can scale the solution to more complex pages.

Personally I'd also use the `.html()` method to set html, not just text, in case the client wants to use a `<br>` tag or `<em>` or `<img>`, etc. Example:

```
$('#sp').children().each(function() {
    $($(this).data().target).html($(this).html());
});
```

Other feedback:

Is there a reason you're using client-side javascript to achieve this? You could do it on the server-side pretty easily (even in javascript with node.js) which would have a number of benefits, including
- Google etc. won't see the content which is an issue for SEO
- Browsers without javascript won't see the content (admittedly this is a very small number and so may not be a concern, but worth pointing out)

Regardless, as a quick-hack-solution, it works.

Comment: Thanks! Ill let you know how this works. Ultimately if there is a better solution id like to here it, but my server limits me to Javascript, and i'm not a big fan of coding in PHP if i don't have to.
Freemarker would be ideal, but again... i have server limitations.

Comment: This worked! thankyou. Overall I would like to advance my methods, but this will due for my current project. Great feedback on the code. It was very helpful.

Comment: Is there an easy way to update this to account for more than text? For instance, if i have a link within the data-target span and want to include it with the text that gets passed to the class.

Comment: Yes; simply replace the `text()` method calls with `html()` method calls. I added another example above. This will copy all text AND html tags into the target element. If you're binding any other behaviours using jQuery (e.g. `$(a).click(...)`) on document load, make sure you do it *after* the code above, as event handlers won't be copied.

Comment: As im working more with my CMS tool, im noticing some possible complications with this method. I am wondering if instead of passing the data-target to a span, if there is a way to replace any text on a page that starts with value "sp." and has a matching property. For example, <p>sp.someSiteProperty</p> where "someSiteProperty is defined in my siteproperties.html. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you want.
It will loop through all elements with classes, in order.  If an element has multiple classes, it will match elements that have all the same classes.  It doesn't filter duplicates, so if an element is matched multiple times, the last match overwrites any previous matches.

```
// save main element
var main = $( '.main-content' );

// for each element in #sp with a class
$( '#sp *[class]' ).each( function() {
    // get all the classes on the element, and make a jQuery selector from them
    var selector = '.' + this.getAttribute( 'class' ).replace( ' ', '.' );

    // find any matching elements in the main element, and set the text
    main.find( selector ).text( $( this ).text() );
});
```

EDIT: Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VwtWD/6/

Comment: Great idea, but in some case i would need to reuse the class multiple times on a page, as the property can exist more than once.