# Site Properties with JS Continued

Tags: javascript, properties

As a result of my question here: 
[Passing site properties with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061351/passing-site-properties-with-javascript)
I'm using the code below to pass text from one div to another in any instance that the data-target is equal to some elements class on a page.

```
$('#sp').children().each(function() {
    $($(this).data().target).html($(this).html());
});
```

However, I'm wondering if instead of passing text to an html element, if i could type text on the page that is equal to the data-target value - then have that text be replaced by the text in data target. For example:

```
<div id="sp" style="display:none;">
<span data-target=".busFullName">My Great Company</span>
</div>

<!-- On some page -->
<p>sp.busFullName has been around since 1920</p>

<!-- Rendered text would be -->
<p>My Great Company has been around since 1920</p>
```

This way I don't have to create an extra tag every time i use a property created.

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can do that, but semantically the code would be meaningless and without JavaScript it would be unintelligible. Still want to do it?

Comment: @JonathanSampson
Yes i would like to still know how to do it. I know a small group of people will have js turned off, but in that case, much of the site functionality will be broken anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should take this approach since it renders your code semantically meaningless and somewhat unintelligible if JavaScript isn't available in the client environment. That being said here is how I *would have* gone about it:

```
(function(){
    // Containing element's ID
    var boxID = "#sp";
    // All data-target elements within containing element
    $("[data-target]", boxID).html(function(a,b){
        // Pattern of #id.targetValue
        var pattern = boxID.slice(1) + $(this).data("target");
        // Find everything in body that contains this pattern
        $(":contains("+pattern+")", "body").html(function(c,d){
            // Replace instances of pattern in html with html
            return d.replace(pattern, b);
        });
    });
})();​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rpHB2/3/

Comment: What way would you suggest that is better? I'm not as experienced in server side coding so i am up for suggestions. If anything, it may be helpful to call to a separate html page that holds the property data-target values, as appose to rendering it on the page. Any thoughts you have on that would help too. Thanks.

Comment: The property is displaying correctly, but the code is breaking alot of other things on the page. Im not sure why at this point, but its removing the body tag from the page when i use it.

Comment: what does (a,b) and (c,d) mean in your script? I believe its being used on another function, and there is a conflict.

Comment: @trobbins26 I've updated it; it shouldn't affect the body element. Be sure to replace `"body"` with an element much closer to all of the elements that may contain your target values.

Comment: Ran into one small snag. When there is more than 1 instance of the name on the page, it will not recognize beyond the first one... any thoughts?

Comment: @trobbins26 The only way that could be true is is you're re-using the ID value, which you shouldn't be. ID values are supposed to be used only once per page.

Comment: Ok your right. I had an instance of my old code on the page which referred to the actual ID of the property. Thanks for your help. your final code worked perfectly.

Comment: Final question... is there any way to call the property values from another page, so i dont have to hide the values on the actual page?

Comment: @trobbins26 That is also possible; but that is an entirely different question. I would encourage you to instead use a JavaScript object-literal to store your values if you wish to approach the problem from this particular angle.

Comment: I just realized that the script is wiping out other scripts within the body of the page when searching for matching content. Is there a way to tell it not to do that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19112/discussion-between-trobbins26-and-jonathan-sampson)